# $(document).ready and xhr

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, document-ready

I code with jquery. My problem is with $(document).ready(function() that calls two functions executing xhr requests

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
getIdCategories();
getnameCategories();
});
</script>
```

Sometimes no function works and sometimes the functions work but they are not working in order!!

the tow functions:

```
function getIdCategories()
{

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET","http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/categories?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(request.readyState==4)
        {
            //alert("Status is:  "+request.status);
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
            {
                response  = request.responseXML.documentElement;
                i=0;
                while(response.getElementsByTagName('category')[i]!=undefined)
                    {
                        idCategories[i]=response.getElementsByTagName('category')[i].getAttribute('id') ;
                        //alert(idCategories[i]);
                        i=i+1;
                    }

             }
         }

    }
    request.send();
}
```

and:

```
function getnameCategories()
{

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(i<idCategories.length)
        {
            request.open("GET","http://patisserie-orient.fr/prestashop/prestashop/api/categories/"+idCategories[i]+"?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);

            request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState==4)
                    {
                        //alert("Status2 is  "+request.status);
                        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)
                        {
                            response1  = request.responseXML.documentElement;
                            nameCategories[i] = response1.getElementsByTagName('language')[0].firstChild.data;
                            //alert(nameCategories[i]);
                            $('#im'+i).html(nameCategories[i]);
                            $('#a'+i).show();
                            i++;


                         }
                     }
                }

            request.send();

        }   
    else
        {
            return;
        }

}
```

Comment: That is to be expected: Ajax calls are asynchronous. You have no guarantee for which will be finished first.

Comment: Why are you using the native `XMLHttpRequest` object when you already have jQuery and its `$.ajax` method? That's like purchasing a new house and sleeping on the street at night.

Comment: Why not use jQuery for your XHR?

Answer (score 1):

`Ajax` call is simply `async` request, that's mean you can't control an order of which one finished first. But you still can solve it by add another `callback`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getIdCategories(function(){
        getnameCategories();
    }); 
});

// in 'getIdCategories'
function getIdCategories(cb) {
    if (/* ajax complete */) {
        // fire callback function
        cb && cb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `$.ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

That's much easier than the native way.

AJAX means ***Asynchronous* JavaScript and XML** where asynchronous means, that the script doesn't wait until the request is done. That means that both of your requests start at the same time and you can not know which one of them is faster. BUT you can start the second request in the callback-function from the first request, so the second request starts when the first one is finished.

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '',
        data: {},
        success:function(data){
            console.log('First request done');
            /* Start second request HERE */
        }

    });
});
```

`$.ajax` also offers synchronous requests. with synchronous requests, the script waits until the request is finished:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '',
        data: {},
        async: false
    });
    console.log('First request done');
    /*Start second request HERE */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's AJAX function has a parameter called async which you can set to false to force synchronous behavior

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success:function(data){
        console.log('First request done');
        /* Start second request HERE */
    }

});
```

});

//call another ajax function

This should allow you to control the order of execution .. unless the first call returns the second will not start

Comment: Your code does not work. Syntax Error, missing `,` after `async:false`